# Does any of the time-series databases (kdb+, InfluxDB, DolphinDB, etc) offer functional programming?

Tags: influxdb, kdb, dolphindb

Would like to use a time-series database with functional programming functionalities

Comment: please follow these instructions while asking a question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

InfluxDB has support for Flux

https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.24/

The long term plan for Flux is to be data source agnostic and work is ongoing for Prometheus support too

Answer (score 0):

DolphinDB fully supports functional programming. Please refer the online document at http://www.dolphindb.com/help/index.html?Chapter7FunctionalProgramming.html

DolphinDB supports:

1. Named function
2. Anonymous function
3. Pure function
4. Lambda expression
5. Partial Application
6. Closure
7. Higher order functions including `any`,`all`,`each`,`loop`,`peach`,`ploop`,`eachLeft`,`eachRight`, `cross`,`eachPre`,`eachPost`,`accumulate`,`reduce`,`call`,`pcall`,`moving`,`roll`,`groupby`,`contextby`,`pivotby`